# Quick password protection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using c# .NET Web Forms 4.0

I have a folder like the following that I need to password protect so anybody wanting to view the page needs to first enter a useridpassword (that we tell them) in order to view the page.

example:

www.abc.com/srlv/

so under srlv I have web pages that need to be password protected.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: Just use Forms Authentication on that folder. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240. You can use the web.config for the username and password rather than a database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# authentication for only subdirectory for any user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378418/c-sharp-authentication-for-only-subdirectory-for-any-user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719554%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719746%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) settings in web.config.

Answer (score 2):

Quickest way is to enable Windows Authentication for that folder, and turn off Anonymous access.

This does mean that you'll need a Windows account for them to log in with (either shared or individual).

Comment: This assumes they are on windows computers, and are internal network users.

Answer (score 0):

The **quickest** (not the best) way is:

Example Page Code. (Obviously include your usual web forms code... masterpages etc..

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="login_form" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="password"  TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Login" OnClick="Login_Click" runat="server" Text="Login" />
</div>

<div id="rest_of_site" runat="server" visible="false">
//rest of site...
</div>
```

Then on the Login_Click event:

```
    protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((username.Text == "Username") & (password.text == "Password"))
              {
                     login_form.visible = false;
                      rest_of_site.visible = true;
               }
            else { //show some error }
        }
```

Comment: Configuring IIS is far quicker than code changes. He'd have to enter this code, compile and redeploy in most circumstances.

Comment: He asked for a quick way, this is a quick way. Configuring IIS will still recompile the website. Your ways also assume windows login is available..

Comment: Configuring IIS will NOT recompile the website. It might recycle the website though (not the same). Although you are correct, I am assuming it's Windows.

Comment: Sorry yes, though it will still kick off any current people using and any data they are entering so same effect.