# c# authentication for only subdirectory for any user

Tags: c#, asp.net

Note this is is a slight variation on a previous question that I had..

I am using c# .NET Web Forms 4.0

I have a folder like the following that I need to password protect so anybody(any external users can also view site) wanting to view the page needs to first enter a userid, password (that we tell them) in order to view the page.

example:

```
    www.abc.com/srlv/
```

so under srlv I have web pages that need to be password protected.

Note that we need to authenticate only if the user goes to a file under /srlv/

Note that these are .html files, not .aspx files.

```
      www.abc.com/srlv/index.html, www.abc.com/srlv/about.html
```

but if the user goes to say www.abc.com it will allow them to view the website without any authentication

I was thinking of using the following:

```
    <authenticaton mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="/srcs/login.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="/srlv/index.aspx" cookieless="UseUri">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
    <user name="Usw" password="pass123"/>
    </credentials>
   </forms>
   </authentication>
```

but how do I say authenticate only if you go to any files within

```
    www.abc.com/srlv/
```

Comment: Just look at: http://forums.iis.net/t/1153712.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the location element in web.config to configure permissions for sections of your website

```
<configuration>
   <location path="srlv">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

This will deny access to anonymous users.

Comment: Thanks, in your example, where do I put what userid/pwd is accepted?

Comment: That is part of authentication. your question shows that you are using forms authentication. The actual user names and passwords depend on your [Membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `web.config` file in the target folder with the following contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="Usw"/>
          <deny users ="*,?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

It simply says, to allow user `Usw` but deny everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Location can help you..

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871

Simply get access to all unauthorized users and block only specific folder.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" /> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to the Default1.aspx page only. It is located in the same folder as this configuration file. -->
        <location path="default1.aspx">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are stored in the Subdir1 folder.  -->
        <location path="subdir1">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
</configuration>
```